# Add value on IntegerField with a button(Django 1.11)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

models.py

```
likes = models.IntegerField()
```

forms.py

```
class LikeForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ("likes",)
```

How could I make a button that add 1 to this IntegerField every time it's clicked? The default value is 0.

I'm guessing I have to use "submit" button but I'm not sure how I can do that with out rendering the form on the page.

Comment: As s start, you may want to set your default equal to 0 in your model: `likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)`

Comment: Does your form include only this single field? If so, you could probably not have to use a form and just post to a view where you increment the `likes` integer

Comment: I set the default to 0. but I don't understand how posting something is possible without a form

Comment: Would I use a role="button" kind of a button or a role="submit" kind of a button?

Comment: You mean like facebook "like"? If you don't want to render the field of the form, you can use a hidden input. But I imagine that you don't want the same user to click multiple times. If so, you need a more complex app.

Comment: @손예준 when I say form I mean the `LikeForm`

Answer (score 1):

In your `views.py` you could add something like this:

```
def record_like_view(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        post.likes += 1
        post.save()
    ...
```

Then in your template:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <a class="btn" href="{% url 'my_app:record_like' post.id %}">Like</a>
</form>
```

You are just posting to a URL. Even though you are still using a form in your template, there is no need for the `LikeForm` in this case. Take a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial04/) Django tutorial for another example.

As far as a user preventing a user from clicking multiple times ([as pointed out by guillermo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51668709/add-value-on-integerfield-with-a-buttondjango-1-11/51687065#comment90318317_51668709)) this would require something a little more complicated.